# Quel est l'équivalent de "hit" et "miss" en français?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

J'utilise de l'aprentissage machine pour classifier des données.
Lorsque qu'une donnée est classifiée correctement, on parle d'un "hit". Lorsqu'elle ne l'est pas, un "miss". Je cherche un équivalent pour placer dans la légende de mes graphiques.

J'ai pensé à *touché/manqué*, *bon/mauvais*, *bien/raté* ou une combinaison de ceux-ci, mais je trouve qu'ils n'ont pas le même "feel" que *hit/miss*. Quand je lit *touché/manqué*, je pense à la bataille navale...

Comment: Sur l'internet, j'ai trouvé ça passe ou ça casse. Je ne sais pas si cela vous convient.

Comment: Effectivement, ça fait un peu penser à la bataille navale. La question est "hit/miss" en anglais ne fait-il pas penser aussi à la bataille navale ? (ou au tir à l'arc / au pistolet)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tout simplement ***succès*** et ***échec***.

Comment: Wow, je ne sais pas comment j'ai manqué ça...

Answer (score 2):

Comme il s'agit d'essais d'application de procédure et qu'il n'est pas souhaité de les catégoriser autrement que en tant que acceptable ou non, certains des termes envisagés peuvent être utilisés .

- bon, … manqué, mauvais, ratés

« Bien » (qui n'est pas un équivalent de » bon », ne convient pas très bien ; « touché » n'a que des applications restreintes dans lesquelles il a un sens le plus souvent littéral.

Des termes plus courants sont « *réussi* » et « *raté* ».  On peut utiliser ces adjectifs en tant que substantifs, les faire précéder de déterminatifs.

- [L'ascenseur](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_ascenseur/YehYDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22les+r%C3%A9ussis%22&pg=PT56&printsec=frontcover)  Dans la bande ou ailleurs, les poètes les faux ratés et les réussis inquiets. Les intellectuels de gauche les maigres qui font du naturisme.
- [Monty Python ! - Petit précis d’iconoclasme](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Monty_Python_Petit_pr%C3%A9cis_d_iconoclasme/MDO2DwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22les+r%C3%A9ussis%22&pg=PT94&printsec=frontcover) Les scripts se rangent en trois piles : les réussis, qui font rire tout le monde ; les moyens, amusants, mais qui manquent encore d'un petit quelque chose qui les fera accéder à la catégorie supérieure
- [Pierre Ceyrac ou la grâce d'aimer](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Pierre_Ceyrac_ou_la_gr%C3%A2ce_d_aimer/KcjLDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22les+r%C3%A9ussis%22&pg=PT76&printsec=frontcover) S'il y a bien deux mondes imperméables l'un à l'autre aux deux extrémités du spectre des apparences, il n'y a pas deux types d'êtres humains, les réussis et les ratés, les compétents et les désorganisés, mais la même humanité, ..
- [Mes jours avec et mes jours sans](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Mes_jours_avec_et_mes_jours_sans/XeIR2wOpADIC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22les+r%C3%A9ussis%22&pg=PA104&printsec=frontcover) D'habitude, je me trouve toujours un tas de choses à faire : trier mes affaires de l'année passée, déchirer les vieux devoirs de géo ratés, encadrer les réussis, aller faire des photos à la gare, me gaver de magazines débiles

Ces adjectifs sont utilisés en particulier pour les mets et les pâtisseries, c'est à dire des produits qui résultent d'opérations complexes sujettes à des erreurs qui peuvent gâcher entièrement le résultat ; similairement, ils sont utilisables pour n'importe quelles procédures au résultat plus ou moins incertain..

On peut dire « x réussis/ratés », mais plus couramment on dit « x de réussis », « x de ratés ».

Answer (score 1):

L'idée d'atteindre la cible ou de la manquer pour ainsi dire :

> (Résultat) positif, (résultat) négatif.
>  Complet, incomplet.
> Réussi, échoué.
>  Correct, incorrect.
>  1, 0.
>  Cible atteinte,
> cible manquée.

Answer (score 1):

En [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/50090/quel-est-l%C3%A9quivalent-de-hit-et-miss-en-fran%C3%A7ais#comment103559_50090) @Lambie avait identifié l'expression « [ça passe ou ça casse](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/casser#aa01107702b8f7ce) », qui rappelle peut-être surtout l'idée de « [make or break](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make-or-break) » en anglais. Indépendamment du sens exact de la locution en français, ses deux éléments « ça passe » et « ça casse » sont certainement courants, adéquats et donc possiblement utiles ici (avec un registre familier), entre autres.